# Why is my firewall preventing me from accessing some websites

Tags: firewall, permissions, router

I have an old Belkin router and when I enable the firewall I cannot access certain websites. For example:

`http://www.avisynth.org`

**With Firewall Enabled**: Main page loads and begins to do a meta refresh which never finishes.

**With Firewall Disabled**: Main page loads and the meta refresh completes as normal and I am taken to the wiki page.

I have not setup any rules in my firewall that would prevent this site from loading, yet it refuses to load unless I have the firewall disabled completely. My router has a hidden page with advanced settings on it for the firewall which I was able to acccess and take a screenshot of, but I did not want to mess with these values unless I absolutely have to do so:

[image]

What might be causing this problem and how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: Thx for adding the img to the post, I could not do so myself since I had under 10 rep points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A meta refresh is an RFC-non-compliant redirection that may very well be blocked by the SPI engine in your firewall. Disable `TCP Connection` Stateful Packet Inspection and try again.

If that causes the site to load, then you've at least narrowed the problem down. After that, you're only recourse is to either update to the latest firmware and hope the problem was addressed, get a new gateway device or leave the TCP part of the SPI engine disabled (...no?).

Comment: Unchecked the TCP Connection and saved the settings, then rebooted the router and the site was still freezing during the meta refresh stage.

Comment: @nosx Next up, it's time to flail! Start unchecking boxes one at a time. The other options don't appear to have any kind of relation to a meta refresh, but... Belkins are weird.

Comment: I will give it a shot, it nothing fixes the problem I will just get a new router. Thx for the help.

Comment: Alternatively, fill in the email section and see what the alert email says when you access the site.  There may also be a logging feature that shows why the request is blocked.